# protect_from_forgery - does order matter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf, csrf-protection

I have read this post https://nvisium.com/blog/2014/09/10/understanding-protectfromforgery/ and if I understood correctly, by default in Rails 3 if we have a controller that looks like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController:Base
  protect_from_forgery
end
```

What will end up happening is that (in case of an attacker) the session will be destroyed. That would mean that if we are doing something like checking if the user is authenticated, since there would be no session, it will stop the request.

So, my question is, I believe that this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController:Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_action :authenticate_user

  private

  def authenticate_user
    raise NotAuthenticated unless session.key?(:user)
  end
end
```

Is the proper way of doing it, instead of

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController:Base
  before_action :authenticate_user
  protect_from_forgery

  private

  def authenticate_user
    raise NotAuthenticated unless session.key?(:user)
  end
end
```

Or in other words, protect_from_forgery should be the first thing that we do in a controller.

Are my assumptions correct, or I am missing something on how the order of operations work in the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of those two methods is not important, no.

The reason has to do with *when* those methods get executed: those are Class-level methods that are executed in the context of the class itself when Ruby loads the file.

Look at the source for `protect_from_forgery`:

```
def protect_from_forgery(options = {})
  options = options.reverse_merge(prepend: false)

  self.forgery_protection_strategy = protection_method_class(options[:with] || :null_session)
  self.request_forgery_protection_token ||= :authenticity_token
  before_action :verify_authenticity_token, options
  append_after_action :verify_same_origin_request
end
```

These are basically macros that add code to your class when they are invoked, a form of metaprogramming. You could replace the method call in the class with setting those things manually and it would be the same.

This all happens when your code first gets loaded, before the application has booted up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still don't understand how this would work in case I want to first do the protect_from_forgery and after verify whatever thing in the session. If I do it the other way around, it wouldn't matter deleting the session because the attacker could have already use it.

Comment: Forgery protection and user authentication are separate concerns. It doesn't matter what order you do them, because no matter what it will happen before the request is responded to.

Comment: I understand that they will happen before the request is responded to. However, if user authentication happens before forgery protection (where session is deleted), we will think that user is properly authenticated, because when it reached we still had the session. Makes sense?

Comment: If the session is deleted during the course of a response, then it will behave as if the user is not authenticated. There is no opportunity to use the session in the meantime. At least that's how it should work, since you have not provided any of your authentication code I can only speak in general terms.

Comment: I have added some dummy code to represent what I meant. It doesn't necessarily need to do with authentication, but rather to me is any code that would rely on the session. If we delete the session AFTER it has been used, then we can be in trouble. That's why I would expect that protect_from_forgery should be the first thing to be executed before any action in a controller.

Comment: So to clarify, to me the issue comes with before filters, they can happen BEFORE we even know we are dealing with a forged request. And to me that happens when the protect_from_forgery is triggered after any before filters. Make sense? This example says it better than me https://www.sourceclear.com/blog/When-Rails-protect_from_forgery-Fails/

Comment: The second example above wouldn't work for two reasons. 1) You're calling an instance method from the class level. 2) Calling a method in that context happens when the code is loaded, not when the class is being used to service a request. You seem to be confusing a method call to wire up behavior with a method call that executes during a request. They are two entirely different contexts.

Comment: FWIW, I generally separate this into multiple controllers. `ApplicationController` is a generic controller that does the forgery protection, and `AuthenticatedController` inherits it and adds authentication checks. This is useful because there are often cases where you need an unauthenticated controller that still might have a form.

Comment: @HommerSmith after reading the article you linked, the issue he is talking about has very little to do with the order of callbacks; it's about memoized ivars not getting cleared when the session is nulled out. If that is happening to you, then you should follow his advice and use the exception strategy.

Comment: Adam, thanks for the explanations. I have edited the code, I meant to have `before_filter` before the `authenticated_user`. My main point, and what I still don't understand (:() is that to me the order matters. If we check for forgery AFTER we have authenticated the user, is different that if we check for forger BEFORE we have authenticated the user. Because in one scenario we would know we are under attack, whereas in the other we wouldn't.  I think the article has something to do with the order. If the forgery prevention happens before the ivar is set, it would never get set afterwards.

Comment: Whether or not the user is authenticated should be entirely irrelevant for the purposes of forgery protection.

Comment: Why is it irrelevant? If we do forgery protection before user is authenticated, we ensure that the user won't be able to authenticate (because we delete session), however if we do if after, we can't ensure what has happened with sessions before we hit the point on ensuring that the request hasn't been forged.

Comment: The entire point of CSRF attacks to is to use a person's valid authentication to perform requests they don't initiate. Whether or not the request is a CSRF attack has nothing whatsoever to do with the validity of a user's authentication.